# What is the use of interface here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

As I learn that interface is also used for encapsulate method but in the following code by casting `ojb` to `MainClass` I am able to access other method from `Mainclass` which I did not declare in interface so now where is encapsulation occur.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IInterface obj = new MainClass();
        Console.WriteLine(((MainClass)obj).FullName()+" " +obj.LastName());
        Console.WriteLine(((MainClass)obj).SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IInterface
{
    string LastName();
}

public class MainClass:IInterface
{
    public  string FullName()
    {
        return "Raman Singh";
    }
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello Sir111";
    }

    public string LastName()
    {
        return "Chauhan";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cast your object to MainClass, the object reference changes from IInterface to MainClass. Therefore, all of MainClasses Mehtods are available since the visibility of said methods depends on the object reference.
If you dont cast your object to MainClass and let its reference be of type IInterface, only the LastName method is visible.

Comment: MainClass Obj1=new MainClass(); 
now in this above line Obj1 is referring to MainClass in heap that means via Obj1 we can access all the method of MainClass, But while using 
Interface obj=new MainClass(); // so ,after this statement MainClass contain memory in heap that means all the method of MainClass avaialble in heap and obj is holding the reference to that memory then why we are not able to access that method by using 
obj.FullName();
obj.SayHello(); etc. but in this case we are only able to access 
obj.LastName();  Why we are able to access that method only which present in interface?

Comment: Because the reference descides, which methods are visible and wich are not. It doesn't really matter, what type the object has.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused among `interface` and `encapsulation`. This is not what interfaces are for.

`An interface contains definitions for a group of related functionalities that a class or a struct can implement. By using interfaces, you can, for example, include behavior from multiple sources in a class.`

whereas

`Encapsulation is to hide the variables or something inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties to use. So the public methods like getter and setter access it and the other classes call these methods for accessing.`

You are actually holding the `MainClass`'s instance in your `obj`, once you cast, as you said. because you actually initialized it using `new MainClass();'. This will call MainClass's constructor to initialize obj. Thats why you can access other methods.

Comment: whatever the way you initialize, if you have to use methods from a class it will call its constructor. So I think as you say "This will call MainClass's constructor to initialize obj. Thats why you can access other methods." is not valid.

Comment: MainClass Obj1=new MainClass(); 
now in this above line Obj1 is referring to MainClass in heap that means via Obj1 we can access all the method of MainClass, But while using 
Interface obj=new MainClass(); // so ,after this statement MainClass contain memory in heap that means all the method of MainClass avaialble in heap and obj is holding the reference to that memory then why we are not able to access that method by using 
obj.FullName();
obj.SayHello(); etc. but in this case we are only able to access 
obj.LastName();  Why we are able to access that method only which present in interface?

Comment: as obj is holding reference to MainClass which is pressent in heap

Answer (score 1):

First thing you mentioned that "interface is also used for encapsulate" which is wrong. Interfaces are used for Abstraction.

And in your code you have created object of your class and also casting it when you are calling the methods. Now if your methods are public then by casting it to your class you can obviously access it.

You can hide other methods by abstraction only when your client doesnt aware about concrete implementation of your class, and must access your methods via interface. Then methods which are declared in interface can be accessible to the client.

*Trying to answer your comment in simple language*. By the statement

```
IInterface obj = new MainClass();
```

you are creating an object of type MainClass. Which will create new instance and returns its reference to variable of type IInterface, but at runtime.

Now when you are assigning reference to interface type, though the object is of MainClass, you are accessing it using interface variable. But interface has no knowledge of other methods in your class which are not inherited from that interface. So no need to talk about object residing in heap at run time, because even compiler would not allow you to access the other methods of your class which interface variable doesn't knows.

You were able to call other methods only because you were casting the interface variable again to your Class type. Hope it makes things easy to understand.

Comment: MainClass Obj1=new MainClass(); 
now in this above line Obj1 is referring to MainClass in heap that means via Obj1 we can access all the method of MainClass, But while using 
Interface obj=new MainClass(); // so ,after this statement MainClass contain memory in heap that means all the method of MainClass avaialble in heap and obj is holding the reference to that memory then why we are not able to access that method by using 
obj.FullName();
obj.SayHello(); etc. but in this case we are only able to access 
obj.LastName();  Why we are able to access that method only which present in interface?

Comment: @GarryChauhan, please look at the updated answer, I have tried to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the same coding to an instance field instead of an Interface as the cast (MainClass)obj is changing it back to it.

Comment: MainClass Obj1=new MainClass(); 
now in this above line Obj1 is referring to MainClass in heap that means via Obj1 we can access all the method of MainClass, But while using 
Interface obj=new MainClass(); // so ,after this statement MainClass contain memory in heap that means all the method of MainClass avaialble in heap and obj is holding the reference to that memory then why we are not able to access that method by using 
obj.FullName();
obj.SayHello(); etc. but in this case we are only able to access 
obj.LastName();  Why we are able to access that method only which present in interface?

Comment: because when you code to an interface you are agreeing to those methods defined in it. I am not sure what happens at heap at that point and internally how the compiler is restricting it.